# Integration Testing redirectedURL for entire path?

Tags: grails, groovy, integration-testing

I am trying to use assert Equals to check the Url that my User controller redirects to after an action. My test keeps failing with this error:

```
junit.framework.ComparisonFailure: expected:</todo[]> but was:</todo[/index]>
```

I just want to check that my function is redirecting to any URL within the /login/ path.
Here is my integration test code:

```
import grails.test.mixin.*
import org.junit.*

/**
 * See the API for {@link grails.test.mixin.web.ControllerUnitTestMixin} for usage instructions
 */
@TestFor(UserController)
class UserControllerTests extends GroovyTestCase {

User user
UserController uc

void setUp() {
//Save a User
 user = new User(userName: "User1", firstName: "User1FN", lastName: "User1LN")
 user.save()

 //Set up UserController
 uc = new UserController()
 }

void tearDown() {
 user.delete()
 }

testHandleLogin(){

 //Setup controller paramaters

 uc.params.userName = user.userName

 //Call the action
 uc.handleLogin()

 //if the action functioned correctly, it put a user object into the session
 def sessUser = uc.session.user
 assert sessUser
 assertEquals("Expected ids to match", user.id, sessUser.id)

 //And the user was redirected to the Todo Page
 assertEquals "/login", uc.response.redirectedUrl
}
```

Is there anyway to use a regular expression, or a method that checks for "/login/(ANYTHING ELSE)"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
assertTrue uc.response.redirectedUrl.startsWith("/login")
```

Comment: That worked, thank you! Don't know why I didn't think about that.